# JetPack Compose - Best practices to define "complex" layouts

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

Hello developer comunity

I´ve been learning Kotlin for 2 years, creating small applications. With new approach of JetPack Compose I´m struggling to learn the good approach and best practice when making my small projects.

I would like to create a UI like this one. With "legacy" use of XML, this was not a problem for me.
Now with Jetpack Compose, I have lot of questions.

[image]

Mainly I would like to know where to define the `Row(){}` and `Column(){}` funtions. Don´t know if they should be in the setContent{} body or in the `@Composable` funtion or in another complete different class

As you can see, there´s a lot of buttons, text, etc. Don´t know if my UI "Structure" should be created in @Composalbe funtions or I should define it in SetContent.

I guess with Jetpack Compose we are not using MVVM anymore, as we are not using XML files for our UI layouts. But perhaps I´m wrong due to my lack of knowledge.

Sorry if this´s an stupid question. I can´t find too many tutorials in Youtube as this is "relative" new. The ones that I find, are the easy one with small examples of a few of Texts, etc.

Thanks in advance for your comments, tips or notes.

Comment: start with [Get started with Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/documentation)

Comment: You are right Philip, I should start learning the basics before jump into the water without know how to swim. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read the [Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) docs and take a look to the official compose samples in [this repository](https://github.com/android/compose-samples), there is a lot of material.

> Don´t know if they should be in the setContent{} body or in the @Composable funtion or in another complete different class

The question is a bit generic, but yes, in your app you might have a `MainActivity` and you will insert all your content in the `setContent`.

*(Example from [Jetsnack app](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetsnack))*

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            JetsnackApp()
        }
    }
}
```

Inside this, you could have a single `@Composable` function, or , **for example**, a [NavHost](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#create-navhost) to switch between different composables.

```kotlin
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "profile") {
    composable("profile") { Profile(/*...*/) }
    composable("friendslist") { FriendsList(/*...*/) }
    /*...*/
}
```

Inside this composables you will put your rows and columns, but nobody prevents you from having a single column in your `setContent`, it all depends on your needs.
The main concept is that you have to image your app as a component tree, [this section](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#paradigm) of the docs explains it very well.

Comment: quick question Stefano, supposly, with JetPack compose we shouldn´t use anymore Views?... or we still combine both aproaches?.

Comment: Ideally the goal of compose is to replace views and xml, but it is completely interoperable and you can still use [Android Views in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose) . Personally I try to use always more Compose over time.